# Is there a single word that is a more vicious connotation of "competition"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm writing a mildly dystopian scenario where competition is taken to vicious extremes, and I was wondering if there was a word that I could use (specifically a noun that was a synonym of "competition") to describe the sort of vicious, cutthroat ... **_________** (the word that I want) that was going on.

I'm specifically looking for a word that doesn't refer to a one-off event (like "contest" or "tug-of-war"), but rather is more about the *state* of things.

Comment: Hmm. What did you rule out when you looked in the thesaurus, so we don't give you useless answers?

Comment: From [thesaurus.com](http://thesaurus.com/browse/competition), I ruled out all the boldly highlighted ones... although "rat race" seems to work, I'd like a few more options along the lines of "rat race", if any exist.

Comment: I'm specifically looking for a word that doesn't refer to a one-off event, but rather is more about the *state* of things. That rules out "bout", "counteraction", "encounter", and "tug-of-war".

Comment: That helps, thanks! Rivalry isn't a one-off, though it may not be cut-throat enough. Dogfight was good, but it sounds one-off. This helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about "[**rivalry**](http://click.reference.com/click/nn1ov4?clksite=dict&clkpage=dic&clkld=260:1&clkorgn=0&clkord=0&clkmod=1clk&clkitem=&clkdest=http%3A%2F%2Fdictionary.reference.com%2Fbrowse%2Fantagonism)," "[**antagonism**](http://click.reference.com/click/nn1ov4?clksite=dict&clkpage=dic&clkld=260:1&clkorgn=0&clkord=0&clkmod=1clk&clkitem=&clkdest=http%3A%2F%2Fdictionary.reference.com%2Fbrowse%2Fantagonism), and "[**oppugnancy**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/oppugnancy)?"

> **rivalry**: the state or condition of competition or antagonism.
>
> **antagonism**: an active hostility or opposition, as between unfriendly or conflicting groups.
>
> **oppugnancy**: the state or quality of being oppugnant; antagonism.

Comment: I ended up using "antagonism". Thanks!

Comment: "Brawl" is a good one.

Comment: "Brawling" would be better, methinks.

Answer (score 1):

Try *death struggle* or *struggle to the death*; such a struggle can last a long time -- for instance in a civil war, which in the worst case can continue for decades.

Comment: *to the death* captures the essence.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following terms:

• *[rat race](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rat_race)*, “An activity or situation which is congested with participants and which is hectic or tedious, especially in the context of a busy, modern urban lifestyle”
• *[slugfest](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/slugfest)*, using a figurative form of the sense “(sports) A game or match in which heavy hits are exchanged”
• *[infighting](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/infighting)*, “Fighting or quarreling among the members of a single group or side”, a term that perhaps fits well in the example sentence

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone can come up with more vicious but off the top of my head there is **death match**.  Not sure you can get more vicious than death.

A good slang piece for a constant death match or an ongoing death match competition is *thunderdome*.

Comment: As I said in a comment above, I'm specifically looking for a word that doesn't refer to a one-off event, but rather is more about the state of things.

Comment: If there's a word that can connote that people are constantly death-matching each other, that would work.